# How to match any one pattern based on the input for a same string using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a string `adajuikodlobauvk01` or `adajuikoplobauvk01`

In both the string differnece is `d` and `p`

If the string is either `adajuikodlobauvk01` or `adajuikoplobauvk01`, the expected output is `adajuiko`

- Code working fine for first string:

  ```
  echo adajuikodlobauvk01 | sed -e 's/\([a-z]*\)d.*/\1/g' -e 's/\([a-z]*\)p.*/\1/g'
  adajuiko
  ```
- For the second string, the output is different from the expectation:

  ```
  echo adajuikoplobauvk01 | sed -e 's/\([a-z]*\)d.*/\1/g' -e 's/\([a-z]*\)p.*/\1/g'
  a
  ```

Please help to match any one pattern based on the given input for the same string.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, your question remains unclear, please edit to clarify: What exactly do you want to accomplish? It seems you simply want to extract the string before the first `p` or `d` in your input string. Also, if you say "not working as expected" - what is the output, and how does it differ from your expectations?

Comment: 1.echo adajuikodlobauvk01 | sed -e 's/\([a-z]*\)d.*/\1/g' -e 's/\([a-z]*\)p.*/\1/g'
output = adajuiko  2. echo adajuikoplobauvk01 | sed -e 's/\([a-z]*\)d.*/\1/g' -e 's/\([a-z]*\)p.*/\1/g'
output = a  for this string adajuikoplobauvk01 output not coming as expexted

Comment: As I said, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/619405/edit) your post to include that information; browsing through the comments is cumbersome. And again, "output not coming as expected" is insufficient to diagnose the problem; please include the actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the expected `adajuiko` output despite the input being either `adajuikodlobauvk01` or `adajuikoplobauvk01`, the `sed` code after the `|` (pipe) character must be this:

```
sed -e 's/\([a-z]*\)[dp].*/\1/g'
```

Where `[dp]` means *it matches either **d** or **p***.